# Does a CE amplifier draw more power when it is amplifying than it is sitting idle?

Tags: power-supply, amplifier

Does a CE amplifier draw more power when it is amplifying than it is sitting idle? In quiescent mode the power consumption would simply be Vcc * Icq. How about the power drawn from the DC power source when it is driving output at full swing? Would it be the same as in quiescent mode?

Comment: What part of the maths can you not figure out? You need also to add whether you're looking at DC signal amplification (signal changes slowly with time) or AC, such as music.

Comment: It is for an audio amplifier. My guess is power consumption should increase when amplifier is working at full swing, proportional to the Vrms*Irms of emitter and collector resistors. In efficiency analysis, battery power is taken as Icq*Vcc.

Comment: On a swing one way, transistor resistance decreasing, yes, current will rise from the rest condition. But what about when the transistor is shutting off and resistance is increasing? Current will fall then and average current will tend towards the at-rest condition. Now your question becomes, "Do the higher current and the lower current balance out to average at the steady state value or not?". I don't know the answer yet, by the way!

Comment: Why isn't total power = DC quiescent + ac RMS?

Comment: See my full answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fReqIf.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. Quiescent, high and low output voltages in a common emitter amplifier.*

- Power is given by \$P = V \cdot I\$.
- In the **quiescent state** I = 5 mA so power dissipated by this part of the amplifier circuit is **60 mW**.
- If we raise the output voltage, Vc, by 1.2 V the collector current must decrease by 1 mA to 4 mA. Now total power is **48 mW**.
- If we lower the output voltage, Vc, by 1.2 V from quiescent the collector current must increase to 6 mA. Total power is **72 mW**.

If we now run continuous squarewave oscillating between the 4 mA and 6 mA conditions with 50% duty cycle the average power will be

$$P = \frac {48 + 72}{2} = \frac {120}{2} = 60 mW$$.

Since this is the same as the quiescent state I reckon that there is no change in output power.

Obviously this would make a poor power amplifier and, for this reason, the [Class AB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amplifier#Class_AB) amplifier was so popular.

Comment: Do you mean 'the *push-pull* amplifier was so popular'?

Comment: Yes. Help me on this one: my understanding is that Class AB is a push-pull configuration biased so that both conduct at cross-over. This increases the quiescent power somewhat but the benefit is greatly reduced crossover distortion.

Comment: Using \$\small I^2R\$, and given constant \$\small R\$, power for 5, 4, 6 is 25, 16, 36, which averages 77/3. For 5, 5, 5 powers will be 25, 25, 25, averaging to 75/3; add to that the +1 and -1 deviation (and square them) for the components that are above 5 and below 5 and you get the correct 77/3. It must obey superposition, therefore you can separate the steady 5 and the alternating component.

Comment: I took the power of the whole circuit Rc, Q1 and Re and not just Rc. V is 12 V for all cases so P is just \$V \cdot I_C\$. I may be misunderstanding what you are saying.

Comment: OK, I'm looking at the power dissipated by the load.

Comment: Class A: conduction angle is 360 degrees. Class AB: more than 180. Class B: 180 exactly. Class C: less than 180. Class AB generally refers to either over-biased Class B or to class A when it runs out of gas. The Wikipedia article you referred to is extremely confused, and indeed flat-out wrong on the question of efficiency. I'll fix it when I get home.

Comment: @Chu: can we decouple the output to the load? And what load should we calculate for?

Comment: I take R1, R3, R5 to be the loads.

Comment: @Chu No, they are the collector load resistors. The load is whatever is connected across the output terminals: in this case, a speaker. It will need to be capacitatively coupled to remove the DC offset.

Comment: I think it holds for sinusoidal as well because we take average power, not rms power.

Comment: @Galaxy, how are you defining 'average power'?

Comment: @Galaxy Average power *is* RMS voltage-based, sinusoidal or not.

Comment: Power (AC) = Vrms * Irms

Comment: @Chu: Can you edit your post to explain what prompted the question and maybe we can give a better explanation. It would be unusual for the collector resistor to be the load in, for example, an audio amplifier as the next stage would present a load too.

Comment: @Galaxy, but only if the rms voltage and current are across and through a resistance.

Comment: @transistor, as you say, the collector resistor is the load, which the BJT sees in parallel with whatever other load may be connected, through a capacitor, say, to the collector terminal. But only for signal frequencies, of course.

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you mean a **class A** CE amplifier like this:
[image]

At it's idle state, a certain quiescent current flows which determines the power taken from the supply. Easy :-)

Now let's see what happens when we apply a certain input signal. I'm assuming that the input signal is small enough so that no significant distortion occurs. The input signal will be equally positive as negative as is normal for audio, I mean that it's average value will be zero.

During the **positive** part of the input signal the transistor will conduct a little bit **more**. This causes the collector current Ic to **increase** proportionally to the input signal. So the circuit will consume a little bit **more** power.

During the **negative** part of the input signal the transistor will conduct a little bit **less**. This causes the collector current Ic to **decrease** proportionally to the input signal. So the circuit will consume a little bit **less** power.

On average, this will cancel out and the average current consumption will be equal to the quiescent power consumption.

However, things will be different depending on, for example:

How you load the output

If for some reason positive and negative do not cancel, this would mean distortion occurs.